# "Masu" verb form vs "Imperfective" verb form

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to put together a chart for myself, to learn the rules for verb conjugation. However, I'm confused at the "Imperfective" and "Perfective" verb conjugations - aren't they just informal versions of the "Masu" verb forms?
To my understanding, the "masu" verb forms are polite ways to say something is either happening or will happen - just like the "Imperfective" verbs(Which appear to just be the dictionary forms?)

- For example, "Tabemasu" vs "Taberu" - both mean that something is either being eaten or will be eaten.

Likewise, the "mashita" verb forms indicate that something has already happened - just like the "perfective" verb forms.

- For example, "Tabemashita" vs "Tabeta" - both mean something has been eaten?

Comment: So, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: For reference, it gets called (im-)perfective [on wikipedia, for example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Okurigana&oldid=643414879#Inflection_examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, "Tabemashita" vs "Tabeta" - both mean something has been eaten?

Yes. They do not differ in meaning, only usage.

Keep in mind there are some times when it's inappropriate to use たべた (*tabeta*); typically these are in more formal (or less familiar) situations. Conversely, there are times when it is inappropriate to use たべました (*tabemashita*); typically these are in more familiar situations, among family or friends, or in certain grammatical constructs. (This would also be the case for *taberu* and *tabemasu*, and so on.)

If you want to read further on the topic, there's quite a bit of discussion and help surrounding these constructs.

- [WordReference forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=558671)
- [Tae Kim's Guide to Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/polite)
- [About.com](http://japanese.about.com/library/weekly/aa031101b.htm)

Comment: So, the "perfective" and "imperfective" verb forms are just the informal variants, then? Same meaning, different usages? It is very confusing why the sites list them as "perfective"/"imperfective" without stating this.

Comment: Ah--I think I see where your confusion is. [*Imperfective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Imperfective) is actually present tense. Both *taberu* and *tabemasu* are the imperfective tense. [*Perfective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Perfective) is the past tense, like *tabeta* and *tabemashita*.

Comment: I see! So "Perfective" vs "Imperfective" isn't just less formal variants of verbs, but rather the tenses used?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: @DanielMartin Yeah, or more precisely, aspects.  But some people consider them tenses instead, and these people refer to them as "past" and "nonpast", so you'll see those names too.